# Different luminosity between preview and render on Sony Vegas 13

Tags: vegas-pro

I currently have a problem with a video I'm editing, when I render it with Sony Vegas 13 (with the Sony AVC/MVC 1080p-30fps "Internet" preset), the resulting video is much darker than the preview (on the same screen), whatever player I use (VLC, Youtube, Windows Media Player).

This is really annoying because I now have to export small chunks of the video to check the resulting luminosity without being able to preview it properly.

I already did dozens of video with the exact same process (same camera, same lighting setup...), except I was using version 12, and I currently can't try to revert back to previous version.

Any idea of what's happening ?
Any suggestion of what I can do to have a preview that matches the rendered video ?

**Some context :**
The video is a man wearing black standing in front of a green screen. The green screen is keyed to a complete black screen.
In order to be able to see the man's body, I adjust the luminosity and contrast so that the clothes are slightly brighter than the background.
After rendering, everything is darker so the clothes are of the same color as the background and you just see a face with hands floating...

**UPDATE**
User altarvic suggested that I check the histograms of both videos and to do that I imported back the rendered video in Vegas. And there, the luminosity is correct in preview (the image is exactly what the preview displayed).
So it seems that the luminosity is wrong on players (at least the ones I tried), but not in Vegas.
Could it be a codec issue ? (Vegas using it's own, player using the machine's).
Or the Vegas preview is not displaying properly the video (I checked I have no output effects applied).

Comment: Have you compared the source and the result using video scopes? (Histogram/Waveform)?

Comment: No, good idea, it'll try that and post the result.

Comment: Oh ! Now that's interesting... Importing the rendered video into Vegas, the luminosity is correct (so scopes are very similar). But PLAYING the video in any player, the luminosity is wrong... Codec issue ?

Comment: Or possibly a color profile in the meta-information that is being respected by Vegas and not by the players.  Could also be an adjustment being applied by your graphics card that is overridden by Vegas.

Comment: Looks like a problem with full range levels 0..255 vs video levels 16..235 (Computer/Studio RGB levels in Vegas). Maybe video players treat video as 0..255, but it is 16..235 Have you applied Levels FX to your video?

Comment: Yes, this is a tip I found and that seem to work (it gives me something acceptable when rendering) but it's also applied to the preview (it's brighter) so the rendered video is still different from the preview, quite hard to apply effects quickly then, as I need to render each time I want to try changing a value.

Comment: @altarvic that helped me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have a solution. Render the video, put it into Vegas again and apply "Sony Levels" with "Computer RGB to Studio RGB". Worked for me.

Comment: Better than rendering twice : you can add the plugin "Levels" (they removed the "Sony") to the Video output FX (in the video preview panel).
Keep it disabled until you render (it will mess up your luminosity, but the rendered video will be good).

Answer (score 2):

Vegas 15 has Finally fixed these issues with the new ACES 1.0 support. To render perfect colors for video AND stills you must ensure the following project project properties are as followed.

https://imghost.io/image/GS3sB

Comment: You should actually embed the image above in the post.  As it is, nobody knows what the heck that link goes to.